# why does `swipl -q` need more RAM and start slowly?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I am using swi-prolog version: 6.3.11.  And there is no ~/.plrc.  `swipl -q` starts VERY slow and needs more RAM given by `top`:

```
size:315M   RES:210M
?- listing.
:- thread_local thread_message_hook/3.
:- dynamic thread_message_hook/3.
:- volatile thread_message_hook/3.
```

However, `swipl -q -f foo.pl` starts VERY quickly and needs few RAM:

```
size:11160K  RES:4236K
```

I am building pl-devel on FreeBSD 9. (I guess `swipl -q` uses system wide initial file which i cannot find ? )

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Couple of thoughts for you:

What happens if you place the contents of your foo.pl file into a new .plrc file in your home dir ?

What happens if you perform "swiple -q -f none"

I don't know the terminology; but I guess there must be a command to show all the rules that have been defined ... If you run the slow swiple command, can you compare how many rulesthere are compared to how many you get when you run with the -f parameter ?

Comment: Even an empty ~/.plrc can cause swipl behave VERY slowly(same as replace .plrc with foo.pl) .  "swipl -q -f none" is VERY slow too. I feel it MUST be a bug of pl-devel !